# look back window based on the Order column and replace it with Orderid and User id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, analytics

I have a table like below

```
----------
user_ID Timestamp   Order_ID    Channel        
----------        
ABC 30/06/2018 10:27    grt12083589 NULL        
----------        
CDE 01/07/2018 10:33    fcd12083589 NULL         
----------        
DEF 01/07/2018 14:40    NULL    1        
----------        
LPG 01/07/2018 14:45    per1133089  NULL        
----------        
ABC 13/06/2018 11:29    NULL    2         
----------        
ABC 04/07/2018 11:57    NULL    1         
----------        
EFG 01/07/2018 12:57    gfd12083705 NULL         
----------        
EFG 28/06/2018 15:24    NULL    3         
----------        
CDE 03/07/2018 01:09    NULL    2         
----------       
ABC 04/03/2018 10:27    NULL    5         
----------        
ABC 05/02/2018 10:27    NULL    1         
----------    
EFG 23/01/2018 15:24    NULL    4 
----------
EFG 04/07/2018 12:57    NULL    2     
----------
```

I need a result like this below by considering the userid and OrderID column and timestamp

I need all the information of a user of 30 days look back window based on the timestamp of Orderid ,If it is more than 30 days ,ignore the information and keep all the the information of that user after the purchase untill the next purchase

It should look like below

```
----------
user_ID Timestamp   Order_ID    Channel 
----------
ABC 30/06/2018 10:27    grt12083589 NULL 
----------
ABC 13/06/2018 11:29    grt12083589 2 
----------
ABC 04/07/2018 11:57    NULL    1 
----------
CDE 01/07/2018 10:33    fcd12083589 NULL 
----------
CDE 03/07/2018 01:09    NULL    2 
----------
DEF 01/07/2018 14:40    NULL    1 
----------
EFG 01/07/2018 12:57    gfd12083705 NULL 
----------
EFG 28/06/2018 15:24    gfd12083705 3
----------
EFG 04/07/2018 12:57    NULL    2 
----------
LPG 01/07/2018 14:45    per1133089  
----------
```

Please help

Comment: Please format this for readability, or preferably, create a SQLFiddle. Also - what have you tried? What are the rules to apply to get the result?

Comment: need information of users based on 30 days before the purchase date (timestamp corresponding to OrderId) and replace the column with the OrderId and keep the activity of user after purchase untill the next purchase

Comment: Is your sample result set incomplete? What happened to the other two last ABC rows in March and Feb? Why are they excluded?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this..

```
declare @table table (
  [user_id] nvarchar(3)
  ,[timestamp] datetime
  ,order_id nvarchar(100)
  ,channel int
  )

  insert into @table values 
    ('ABC', '30-jun-2018 10:27',  'grt12083589' , NULL    ),
    ('CDE', '01-jul-2018 10:33',  'fcd12083589' , NULL    ),
    ('DEF', '01-jul-2018 14:40',  NULL        , 1            ),
    ('LPG', '01-jul-2018 14:45',  'per1133089'  , NULL    ),
    ('ABC', '13-jun-2018 11:29',  NULL          , 2      ), 
    ('ABC', '04-jul-2018 11:57',  NULL          , 1      ), 
    ('EFG', '01-jul-2018 12:57',  'gfd12083705' , NULL    ),
    ('EFG', '28-jun-2018 15:24',  NULL        , 3            ),
    ('CDE', '03-jul-2018 01:09',  NULL        , 2            ),
    ('ABC', '04-mar-2018 10:27',  NULL        , 5            ),
    ('ABC', '05-feb-2018 10:27',  NULL        , 1            ),
    ('EFG', '23-jan-2018 15:24',  NULL        , 4            ),
    ('EFG', '04-jul-2018 12:57',  NULL        , 2            )


   ;with cte as 
   (
      select  DATEADD(day,-30,max([timestamp])) as max_timestamp,[user_id] 
      from @table
      group by [user_id] 
   )

    select t1.* from @table t1
    where [timestamp]> (select max_timestamp from cte t2  where t2.[user_id]=t1.[user_id]  )
    order by [user_id] asc,order_id desc,[timestamp] desc
```

You will get the result as :

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+
| user_id |        timestamp        |  order_id   | channel |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+
| ABC     | 2018-06-30 10:27:00.000 | grt12083589 | NULL    |
| ABC     | 2018-07-04 11:57:00.000 | NULL        | 1       |
| ABC     | 2018-06-13 11:29:00.000 | NULL        | 2       |
| CDE     | 2018-07-01 10:33:00.000 | fcd12083589 | NULL    |
| CDE     | 2018-07-03 01:09:00.000 | NULL        | 2       |
| DEF     | 2018-07-01 14:40:00.000 | NULL        | 1       |
| EFG     | 2018-07-01 12:57:00.000 | gfd12083705 | NULL    |
| EFG     | 2018-07-04 12:57:00.000 | NULL        | 2       |
| EFG     | 2018-06-28 15:24:00.000 | NULL        | 3       |
| LPG     | 2018-07-01 14:45:00.000 | per1133089  | NULL    |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+---------+
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GLP40112)

Comment: Many thanks for your help, how  to update the OrderID  column corresponding to userid timestamp before 30 days as shown in my result output.many thanks in advance  ABC 30/06/2018 10:27    grt12083589 NULL 
----------
ABC 13/06/2018 11:29    grt12083589 2 
----------
ABC 04/07/2018 11:57    NULL    1